# Custom Labels in Excel 10

Tags: vb.net, excel

Using Excel 10 VB, I can add Series Name, Category Name, and/or value.  Is there a way to add a custome name referenced in a cell location to a chart?

I can do it in Ver 13, but have to supply verion for Ver 10 folks.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: Also Are you doing this in Excel (VBA) or VB.Net?